# How to draw a vertical line in scilab

Tags: scilab

I'm trying to draw clock cycle however Im finding trouble in drawing the vertical line

```
clear;
close;
clc;
clf;
x=[1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0]

z=0;
for i=1:length(x)
    
    subplot(1,1,1)
    a=gca();
    a.data_bounds=[0,-0.05;length(x),1.5]
    a.grid =[1 ,-1]
    title ('Clock')
    t2=[z:0.5:z+0.5]
    plot(t2,1)
    t2=[z+0.5:0.5:z+1]
    plot(t2,0)
    
    z=z+1    
end
```

I'm trying to make each plot connected through a vertical line

[This is what I'm trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU8If.png)

[This is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvu8I.png)

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
    t2=[z:0.5:z+0.5]
    plot(t2,1)
    e = z +0.5
    plot([e,e],[1 0])
    
    t2=[z+0.5:0.5:z+1]
    plot(t2,0)
    e = z + 1
    plot([e,e],[1 0])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler answer, without any explicit `for`loop:

```
nH = 9;
t = 0:0.5:nH;
t = [t ; t](2:$-1);
y = (ones(1, nH) .*. [1 1 -1 -1] + 1)/2;

clf
plot(t, y)
gca().grid = [1 ,-1];
gca().data_bounds(3:4) = [-0.2 1.6];
```

[image]